# Color the portions of chart using "Google 3D Pie chart API" in Android

Tags: javascript, android, colors, charts, highcharts

I am using the link given below to show pie chart in my android application successfully, but now I want to color the each portion as my desire of the chart.

What do I have to do? I have to pass any extra parameter with this URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution ...

Visit the following Link :  https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts

And add this part of code in your URL "&chco=FFFF10,FF0000,FF00FF" this will work like charm for you.